# MySQL LIKE vs BOOLEAN MODE (FULLTEXT) where and when to use?

Tags: java, mysql, full-text-search

I want to search from a lot of records by name. When i use MySQL `LIKE` it's getting too much time to search. What if I use `fulltext` search `match(name) against(*linebre*) IN BOOLEAN MODE` on my code, will it be faster?

and i checked on my records

**MySQL Like**

```
MariaDB [****]> select count(*) from contents where tags like "%а%";
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    16927 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

**FullText**

```
MariaDB [****]> select count(*) from contents where match(tags) against('*а*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     6665 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

seems like i'm using wrong on `FULLTEXT` search. there has a huge difference.

how can i use it? and which one is handy to use?

Comment: why don't you try it and see?

Comment: i tried it. but seems like i'm coding wrong. how can i use for this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what is the requirement for a `count` here but you can try

```
select count(*) from contents where match(tags) against('а' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

hope that helps

Comment: hehe count is just to know its showing right answers or no

Comment: then try the `IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE`